# how to merge & split a vriable in manger using Entity Framework in C#?

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework, boilerplate

I' m using boilerplate frame work with entity framework,I want two merge two variables . After that split variables inside that array.
my two array is

```
var permission = _permissionManager.GetAllPermissions();
var privilege = 
_roleManager.GetGrantedPermissionsAsync(privilegeSearchModel.RoleId).Result.ToList();
```

I used for merging like this way

```
  var permissionlist = privilege.Concat(permission).ToList();
```

> i wish  arrray become like this

```
permissionLsit={{name:Settings,isgrated:1}{name:Settings-user,isgrated:1},
{name:Setings-user-Edit,isgranted:0},{name:Setings-user-Delete,isgranted:1},
{name:Setings-user-view,isgranted:1},{name:Property,isgrated:1},{name:Property-
Rent,isgrated:1},{name:Property-Rent-view,isgrated:1}.........}
```

My expected output is given below

```
{ {settings=1,Usersettings=1,view=1,edit=0,delete=1}
{propert=1,propertyRent=1,view=1,edit=0,delete=0}...}
```

how can it possible? any one can help me!...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Union statement. Try the following:

```
var newList = privilege.Union(permission).ToList();
```